# What's the best way to increment a string [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable that returns me the url of an image, and in this url the id of the image can vary the quantity of numbers... what would be the best way to complement the id like this:

As it is: http://mydomain.com.br/arquivos/ids/1318090/94842_1.jpg

How to stay: http://mydomain.com.br/arquivos/ids/1318090-500-500/94842_1.jpg

In short, I need to add the "-500-500" into id

Sorry... A Example:

```
var a = "http://mydomain.com.br/arquivos/ids/1318090/94842_1.jpg";
var b = "-500-500";
var position = 43;
var output = [a.slice(0, position), b, a.slice(position)].join('');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Sorry, I refresh with a exemple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like following:

```
var url = "http://mydomain.com.br/arquivos/ids/1318090/94842_1.jpg";
var index = url.lastIndexOf("/");
var new_url = url.slice(0, index) + "-500-500" + url.slice(index);
```

Comment: nice and clean solution mate!

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation :)

Comment: Thanks... It is :)

Answer (score 1):

```
link = link.split("/").reduce((r,c,i)=>r+c+i===5?"-500-500": "","").join("/");
```

Simply add it behind the 6th element ( that are seperated by / ) .

Comment: Thanks @Jonas w. But the solution of Mahbubul Islam is perfect for me.

Comment: @Jonas w this is way ahead man, kinda convoluted solution but nice one.

Comment: @danish *convoluted* also called *functional approach* ... :)

Answer (score 1):

you have not shown any progress what you did! How about i gave you the hint?

assign a variable to your string, `split` it using `\` and then find the exact occurrence to change by this `[0]` of course change the number according to your desire where change is required.

Now get your new string and concate with old in a way that you get desired results. Example

```
var str = "http://mydomain.com.br/arquivos/ids/1318090/94842_1.jpg";
var newstr = str.split('/')[5];
var prepstr = newstr + "something";
```

then finally,

```
str + prepstr;
```

Comment: Thanks Danish. But the solution of @Mahbubul Islam is perfect for me.

Comment: no problem @RodrigoDias Keep learning and keep up the good work!